# Owl-Carousel 2 прекращает работу autoplay и loop если страница неактивна

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, owl-carousel

Использую карусель Owl-Carousel 2 со стандартными объявлением и html-разметкой. Скрипты css и js помещены в головную часть страницы head, как и последняя версия jquery (выше скрипта js карусели естественно). При первичной загрузке работает отлично! Проблема в том, что при переходе в браузере на другую страницу (если открыты разные страницы) или при минимизации браузера работа autoplay и loop после возврата на страницу карусели прекращается. Восстановить их можно лишь кликнув на любом навигационном элементе или после перезагрузки самой страницы. Пробовал поместить объявления скриптов в конец блока body и размещать там же следующий код повторной инициализации:

```js
var $carousel = $('.owl-carousel');
var owl = $carousel.data('owlCarousel');
owl.trigger("refresh.owl.carousel");
```

Эффект никакой. Восстановление работы autoplay и loop только после клика на любом навигационном элементе или после перезагрузки страницы. Прошу совета в какой области вести поиск ошибки или как решить данную проблему. Возможно я что-то упускаю или неверно что-то объявил. Спасибо за любую помощь.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте использовать stopOnHover: true

Мне помогло!

Comment: Постарайтесь писать ответы более развернутыми. Может какой простой пример добавьте.